# Is there any formula for $\phi(\frac{a}{b})$, where $b|a$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was just messing around with the Euler Totient function when I thought of this question, so it is not in some problem that I'm trying to solve. I couldn't find the answer anywhere else.

All I wonder is that if there is some kind of formula for finding $\phi(\frac{a}{b})$ (of course here $b|a$ because $\phi(n)$ isn't defined for non-integers). When I say formula I mean something like e.g. $\phi(nm)=\phi(n)\phi(m)\frac{d}{\phi(d)}$ where $d = \operatorname{gcd}(n,m)$

Comment: you can find many formulas on the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function

Comment: @Vinyl_cape_jawa Yes, I know, that's always the first place I look for formulas, but in this case there is none.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already wrote down the formula, you just have to rework it. Let $n = a/b, m = b$, and $d = \gcd(a/b, b)$.

$$\phi(a) = \phi\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)\phi\left(b\right)\frac{d}{\phi\left(d\right)}$$

$$\phi\left(\frac{a}{b}\right) = \frac{\phi(a)}{\phi(b)} \cdot \frac{\phi(d)}{d} $$

Comment: Thank you, I didn't see it!